# PHP contact form is not working

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add a contact form to my website but each time I click send it takes me to a black window and the address bar says contact.php. Also it doesn't redirect back.
My website is hosted as an application using the google app engine.

I tried literally everything but I can't get it to work.

Below is my **HTML** code:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <p>Your name</p>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <p>Your e-mail</p>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <p>Message</p>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
</form>
```

and here is my **PHP** code:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'email@here.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message.');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed.');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mail server, PHP doesn't sent mails by itself. Install one first. And yea, text area is missing close tag.

Comment: Are you using windows o linux?

Comment: Crap, im sorry: [Working Link](http://vertstudios.com/blog/windows-php-mail-server-installation-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing textarea tag in your form.  I tried the code as contact.php on my server and it works.  I agree with itachi, you need to turn on error reporting.

Why not make contact.php a full page and get rid of the redirect altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me. Your if else condition is not working properly if fields has no values then still it gives thank you message.